# Compute multivariate normal density for multiple datapoints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If I have N datapoints, each with D dimensions, is there a way to quickly compute the value of multivariate gaussian pdf for each datapoint without using a for loop? For one datapoint x with D dimensions, I can calculate the value of the pdf as follows (scipy):

```
multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)
```

where x is 1xD, mean is 1xD, cov is DxD. I want to compute this so that I get an array of pdfs, length N, by doing something like:

```
multivariate_normal.pdf(X, mean, cov)
```

where X is NxD. Each datapoint has the same mean and covariance. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a suitable array x, there are no issues. Here the pdf is evaluated at 5 random points of 2-dimensional space.

```
mean = np.array([3, 2])
cov = np.array([[4, 1], [1, 5]])
x = np.random.uniform(size=(5, 2))

multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)
```

returns

```
array([ 0.01424279,  0.01537563,  0.01758953,  0.01994425,  0.01584357])
```